# Switch to Particular Tab and close other tabs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am opening one site in chrome but before that I am getting chrome settings window in every run.I want to switch to new window and close the previous one.I have tried driver.close() and driver.quit() but the whole window is getting closed.

1)How can I find out which one is taken as child window and which one is taken as parent window?
2)How to close the window coming as "chrome settings"?
Below is the code I am using:

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".//chromedriver.exe");

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://demoqa.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //windows maximize
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
        // Switch to new window opened
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

Comment: i have tried opening that site in my chrome. it's not opening any security settings for me

Comment: how many total tabs are there? once the script has been launched where the selenium focus is? in that security page?

Comment: Yes..That chrome settings is not coming in other system..only in my system.. :( So including chrome settings.. i am getting two tabs and want to switch to demoqa site tab and close the chrome setting tab..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to get the current window id(parent) and also get all the window's id including current window. Then switch to all of the available windows one by one and check if it's the parent window then close it.

Lets say you are having two tabs opened now and you are in first tab(parent). In this case it will be the security tab.

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //All tab's id (security + toolsQA) and storing it.
    Set<String> all = driver.getWindowHandles();

    //Get all the tab id's including security and iterate
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
       if(winHandle.equals(winHandleBefore))
       {
         //Condition satisfied. Switching to the security tab and closing it
         driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
         driver.close();

       }
    }
    //Now the security tab will be closed we need to switch to the toolsQA whose id is in "all"
    //Removing the security tab id from all.
    all.remove(winHandleBefore);
    //Now we have only one toolsqa id in "all"
    for(String winHandle : all)
    {

         driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
         //Now in toolsQA
```

**Note :** Since we are having only two tabs in this case, this solution might not be the best but this should work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks..it worked..:)

Just a little change of code needed here:

if(!winHandle.equals(winHandleBefore)) 
//! needed

as it is taking toolsqa as parent.

Thanks for your support.. :)

Comment: Okay. That's fine.